# How do you resend a transaction without running a full node?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

The answers to [the canonical "my transaction has been pending for too long" question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/67066) require hundreds of GB of hard drive and bandwidth. I cannot meet such requirements to run a full node.

How can a 15 sat/B, 389 B Segwit unconfirmed transaction to Coinbase be replaced (transaction inputs double-spent?) with a higher transaction fee without downloading the entire blockchain on a full node?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any software which is capable of broadcasting a transaction. This could be another wallet software such as Electrum or a command line tool like [`bitcoin-submittx`](https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-submittx).

Comment: That github page indicates a problem with Segwit. Can it be used to replace an unconfirmed transaction that used Segwit? Should novices use Electrum instead of that command line tool?

Comment: Novices should use something else as command line tools are harder for most people to understand and use.